# Can GET from a Grails controller but I am getting a 404 for the POST

Tags: grails, prototype

I have my url mappings set up to receive both GET and POST requests. I am using Prototype AJAX. This is my function:

```
 function savePrefs(){
        var user = document.getElementById('username').innerHTML;
        var bounds = window.map.getExtent();
        var Lat = bounds.left + (bounds.right - bounds.left) / 2;
        var Long = bounds.bottom + (bounds.top - bounds.bottom) / 2;
        var Zoom = window.map.getZoom();
        var json = new Object;
        var url = "Prefs";
        json.username = user;
        json.lat = Lat;
        json.long = Long;
        json.Zoom = Zoom;
        json = JSON.stringify(json);
        alert(json);
        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method:'post',
            contentType:'application/json',
            postBody:json,
            asynchronous:true,
            onSuccess: function (req) {
                alert(req);
            }

        });        }
```

I keep getting a 404 error in the console. But when I load the page, I do a GET request and it responds fine. Any ideas?

Comment: `var url = "Prefs";`... Look in the firebug console or any other console. I'm pretty sure that the url that you hit the GET isn't the same of your post.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a relative URL in the AJAX post. AJAX URLs have to be provided in their "absolute" form. You can't use relative URLs like you can with links in your page.

Comment: The GET and POST are both set up under the same URL mappings. So, Prefs is for both of them. I also tried to use the literal URL and it did not work. And you don't need the absolute url if you have your URL mappings set up. It is a bad idea to do hard code that for dev vs deployment.

Comment: Got it to work. I have no idea why it wasn't working. I changed nothing and redeployed in the morning and it worked. Bizarre. But thanks for the help.